# How to effectively prevent document scrolling in android?

Tags: javascript, android, css, mobile-website

I have a website where I'd like to implement drag-and-drop in both desktop and mobile. I was able to do it in the desktop, and the mobile interface works as well, as long as the document doesn't scroll. Unfortunately, I haven't found a consistent way to prevent the document from scrolling in mobile browsers.

Here is what I have so far:

- On the iPhone, I can preventDefault on either touchstart or touchmove. This lets me handle the touchmove event before calling preventDefault and canceling the document scroll.
- On the Android, I must prevent touchstart!
  Unfortunately, however, if I prevent touchstart, I don't get any more touchmove events! So are there any better ways to do it? Perhaps making everything position: fixed on the fly when someone does touchstart?

I would have been happy to overflow: auto, but unfortunately I think that only works in Android 4, i.e. tons of Android users won't be able to use it. Meanwhile, iScroll and other solutions seem to be kind of slow and -- worse yet -- don't really prevent the document scrolling either. Is this still the case?

In short, what to do?

Comment: did you try this:

document.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}, false);

Comment: yes, that prevents the touchmove event, but on Android this doesn't cancel the scrolling -- only preventing touchstart does, but then I don't get any touchmove events to process either!